# Comparing an ArrayList of ArrayLists to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, compare, contains

In the below example, how would I go about comparing the contents of `ArrayList al4` to either of the other `ArrayList`s? In the same manner I compared `al1` to `al2`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Details {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        al1.add("hi");
        al1.add("How are you");
        al1.add("Good Morning");
        al1.add("bye");
        al1.add("Good night");

    ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    al2.add("Howdy");
    al2.add("Good Evening");
    al2.add("bye");
    al2.add("Good night");

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al4 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    al4.add(al1);

    // Storing the comparison output in ArrayList<String>
    ArrayList<String> al3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String temp : al1)
        al3.add(al2.contains(temp) ? "Yes" : "No");
    System.out.println(al3);

    }
}
```

Output for `al3`

```
[No, No, No, Yes, Yes]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a little on what you mean. You can't *directly* compare `al4` with `al2`, because they're of different types: one is an `ArrayList<String>` and one is an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

When you compare `al1` and `al2`, what you're doing is determining, for each element of `al1`, whether it occurs *anywhere* in `al2`. I presume this is what you want. You are *not* deciding whether it occurs in the same place in `al2`.

The first thing you should do is improve this comparison, which is rather inefficient. Since you don't care about ordering of `al2`, you should rewrite the comparison like this:

```
ArrayList<String> al3 = new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> al2set = new HashSet<String>(al2);
for (String temp : al1)
    al3.add(al2set.contains(temp) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

This is a lot more efficient because you don't have to traverse the whole of `al2` for each lookup.

Now, if you want to compare your list of lists with a list, I can only assume that you mean you want to tell, for each element of any of the lists in `al4`, whether it occurs in `al2`. If so, then you want

```
ArrayList<String> al3 = new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> al2set = new HashSet<String>(al2);
for (List<String> tempList : al4)
    for (String temp : tempList)
        al3.add(al2set.contains(temp) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

This will give you one flat `ArrayList<String>`, recording, for each element of the lists of `al4`, whether that element was in `al2` somewhere.

It is possible that you want your result to be an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, so that the result mimics the structure of `al4`, in which case it's only slightly more complicated:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> al3list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
Set<String> al2set = new HashSet<String>(al2);
for (List<String> tempList : al4) {
    ArrayList<String> al3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String temp : tempList)
        al3.add(al2set.contains(temp) ? "Yes" : "No");
    al3list.add(al3);
}
```

After executing this, `a3list` will have the same structure as `al4`, and each element of each list will be either `"Yes"` or `"No"`, according to whether the corresponding element in `al4` was contained somewhere in `al2`.

Comment: Excellent and thorough explanation. Thanks ever so much, I really do appreciate it!

Comment: In this example, when I add another `ArrayList` to `al4`, on Execution it seems to add a duplication of the previous index to the next index, along with the correct values that should be stored in that index.

Comment: @user2988501 I'm not sure I follow what you mean. The code I gave will process the *whole* of `al4`. Are you wanting to add a new list to `al4` and then just process that last bit? You might need to give an example if I've misunderstood what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, how would I edit the for loop, so that if I added another 'ArrayList' to the 'al4' it wouldn't cause duplicate values in 'al3list'.

Comment: I figured it out, I had a bracket in the wrong place!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method like this.

```
public static boolean[] compare(ArrayList<String> al1, ArrayList<String> al2) {

        boolean result[] = new boolean[al1.size()]; // result

        int i = 0;  // index

        /*
         * Test if an element of al1 occurs in al2
         */
        for(String s : al1) {
            if(al2.contains(s)) {
                result[i] = true;
            }
            else {
                result[i] = false;
            }
            i++;    // increment
        }

        return result; 
    }
```

And after you can call this method and display the result

```
boolean result[] = compare(al1, al2);

for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)  {
    System.out.print(result[i] + " ");
}
```